# iOS Tumblr Integration using oauth

Tags: ios, oauth, uiwebview, tumblr

Trying to understand how this all works. New to oauth and api integrations.
Not looking for a better way. Looking to understand and expand on what this is doing.

I followed [this tutorial](http://codegerms.com/login-with-tumblr-in-uiwebview-using-xcode-6-part-1/) and have it working
through part 3.

I kind of understand, but having a hard time connecting the code to the Tumblr API documentation.

The tutorial leaves off with having the user's Access Token.

How do I use the Access Token to get the users info with [api.tumblr.com/v2/user/info](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#user-methods) in xcode?

With this information I might be able to put together an understanding in my head.

Code example would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ir100,
use the same acess_token and secret_key you generated via OAuth Library and just change your request url(API) because every time you have to send other parameter for API call.

```
_consumer = [[OAConsumer alloc] initWithKey: _consumerKey secret: _secretKey];

OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: url consumer: _consumer token:token realm:nil signatureProvider: nil] ;
if (!request) return;

if (self.pin.length)
    token.verifier = _pin;

[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];

if (_api)
[request setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];

NSMutableArray *params =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:request.oa_parameters];
request.oa_parameters = params;

OADataFetcher               *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init] ;
[fetcher fetchDataWithRequest: request delegate: self didFinishSelector: success didFailSelector: fail];
```